# How to open a pdf in local storage in Angular2 HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, iframe

I'am trying to open a .pdf file in local storage using an iFrame.
Code I tried is as follows.

**In HTML file**

```
<object [data]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(selectedItem.FilePath)" type="application/pdf">
<iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(selectedItem.FilePath)">
</iframe>
</object>
```

**in Component.ts file**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

---

```
   this.selectedItem.FilePath="D:\WorkDir\Exceline\US.Exceline.GMS\US.Common.Web.Web\DocumentStore\beta\1\145\pdf.pdf"
```

without the sanitizer it will throw an exception as follows.

```
ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see 
http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
    at DomSanitizerImpl.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-
browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize 
(platform-browser.es5.js:3970)
    at setElementAttribute (core.es5.js:9320)
    at checkAndUpdateElementValue (core.es5.js:9291)
    at checkAndUpdateElementInline (core.es5.js:9238)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12325)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12271)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13132)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.es5.js:13111)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (McDocumentsComponent.html:110)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13096)
```

With sanitizer it won't open the file.
What am I doing wrong ?
How can I open a .pdf file in the local server. ?

Answer (score 0):

The path seems not correct:

```
this.selectedItem.FilePath="D:\WorkDir\Exceline\US.Exceline.GMS\US.Common.Web.Web\DocumentStoreD:\WorkDir\Exceline\US.Exceline.GMS\US.Common.Web.Web\DocumentStore\beta\1\145\pdf.pdf"
```

You repeat twice the part

```
D:\WorkDir\Exceline\US.Exceline.GMS\US.Common.Web.Web\DocumentStore
```

Comment: it should be in a comment.